# Strange Behavior with pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have a rather strange problem, despite locking the critical code section in a thread that I am launching, I do not get the right results -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#define NUMTAGS 6

std::mutex foo,bar;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

typedef struct PKT{
  int ii;
  int jj;
}pkt;
  

void *print(void *pk)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  pkt *x = (pkt *)pk;
  printf("--> %d %d %d\n", x->ii, x->jj, x->ii*NUMTAGS + x->jj); 
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  int count = 3;
  int ii, jj;

  pthread_t t_id[count*NUMTAGS];
  int   t_status[count*NUMTAGS];
  pkt p;
  pkt *p_p = &p;
  
  for(ii=0; ii < count; ii+=1){
    for(jj=0; jj < NUMTAGS; jj+=1){
      p.ii = ii;
      p.jj = jj;
      //printf("<> %d %d %d\n", p_p->ii, p_p->jj, p_p->ii*NUMTAGS + p_p->jj);
      t_status[ii*NUMTAGS + jj]=pthread_create(&t_id[ii*NUMTAGS + jj], NULL, print, (void*)p_p);
    }
  }
    
 for(ii=0; ii < count; ii+=1){
    for(jj=0; jj < NUMTAGS; jj+=1){
      pthread_join(t_id[ii*NUMTAGS + jj], NULL);
    }
  }
 
}
```

The resulting answer is randomly wrong...

```
--> 0 3 3
--> 1 0 6
--> 1 0 6
--> 1 0 6
--> 1 0 6
--> 1 0 6
--> 1 1 7
--> 1 2 8
--> 1 3 9
--> 1 5 11
--> 2 0 12
--> 2 0 12
--> 2 1 13
--> 2 3 15
--> 2 4 16
--> 2 5 17
--> 2 5 17
--> 2 5 17
```

Can someone tell me what is the correct way to launch the print thread and have the body execute atomically ?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Just out of curiousity what C++ version are you using,? Since C++11 it is no longer needed to use pthreads, you can use std::async or std::thread. Note that the order in which code in threads is executed is always up to the OS's thread scheduler, there is no guarantee on a strict order in which code is run.

Comment: Yes, that is correct Pepjin, I am NOT using C++11 although I am planning to use the C++ thread library when I eventually transition

Comment: I see :), did you already get the answer you were looking for?  When you transition also have a look at std::unique_lock, it automatically unlocks std::mutex when it goes out of scope.

Comment: (1)  `pthread_t t_id[count*NUMTAGS];` is not standard C++. (2) You include `<thread>` and `<mutex>` and then claim you are not using C++11. Remove these #include directives, and the program becomes a valid C (not C++) program.

Comment: Hi Pepin and "n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m", Yes, I plan on cleaning up this program and use std::unique_lock and std::mutex instead. The program has to be C++, apologies for mixing up the two in this example. I should be good for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks David,
After your comment, I modified my code and it now works -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#define NUMTAGS 6

std::mutex foo,bar;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

typedef struct PKT{
  int ii;
  int jj;
}pkt;
  

void *print(void *pk)
{

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  
  pkt *x = (pkt *)pk;
  printf("--> %d %d %d\n", x->ii, x->jj, x->ii*NUMTAGS + x->jj);

  
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  int count = 3;
  int ii, jj;

  pthread_t t_id[count*NUMTAGS];
  int   t_status[count*NUMTAGS];
  pkt p[count*NUMTAGS];
  pkt *p_p = p;



/*pre-assigned structure before launching thread*/
   for(ii=0; ii < count; ii+=1){
    for(jj=0; jj < NUMTAGS; jj+=1){
      p[NUMTAGS*ii + jj].ii= ii;
      p[NUMTAGS*ii + jj].jj= jj;
    }
   }
  
  for(ii=0; ii < count; ii+=1){
    /*assign p_p[i] to thread i*/
    for(jj=0; jj < NUMTAGS; jj+=1, p_p+=1){
      //printf("<> %d %d %d\n", p_p->ii, p_p->jj, p_p->ii*NUMTAGS + p_p->jj);
      t_status[ii*NUMTAGS + jj]=pthread_create(&t_id[ii*NUMTAGS + jj], NULL, print, (void*)p_p);
    }
  }
    
 for(ii=0; ii < count; ii+=1){
    for(jj=0; jj < NUMTAGS; jj+=1){
      pthread_join(t_id[ii*NUMTAGS + jj], NULL);
    }
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

First, the thread that executes `main` modifies `p.ii` and `p.jj` without holding the mutex. So when the thread you created goes to read `ii` and `jj`, anything can happen because they may be in the process of being modified.

Second, it's not clear what behavior you expect and why. The output you see is perfectly reasonable. You say it's "wrong" but don't explain why it's wrong. You don't force any ordering between the thread running `main` and the printing threads. The thread running `main` might manage to change `ii` and `jj` several times before the thread created manages to run.

Why do you think two threads printing the same thing is "wrong"? What do you think forces the first thread to finish before the `main` thread modifies `ii` and `jj` more than once?

Comment: Ah.. thanks for your response, I would like the output to be such that the sequence generated by ii and jj are correctly passed to the thread routine (print).  You do bring up a good point that the variables (ii,jj) should be preassigned prior to passing to the thread... So basically I would like to see that the output be like what it would otherwise be if I did not use the threads (albeit not in the sequenced order).....

Comment: @RajatMitra You pass every thread exactly the same parameters. How are you expecting them to magically get different information?

Comment: Hi David, Actually I am creating the parameter set in the parameter array "p". The (NUMTAGS*ii + jj) th. thread  gets the corresponding indexed parameter. I have modified the example to demonstrate...